# Oracle not providing osuser when there is a connection from a java program

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I am trying to connect to my remote oracle database, and it is locked down and has a white list of users and pc's that they can connect from. However, oracle is not providing OSUSER when I attempt the connection so I'm getting denied.

Here is how I am connecting:

```
public static final String CONNECTION_STRING =  "jdbc:oracle:thin:@myip:port:db";
public static final java.util.Properties CONNECTION_PROPERTIES = new java.util.Properties();
static {
    CONNECTION_PROPERTIES.setProperty("password","password"); 
    CONNECTION_PROPERTIES.setProperty("user","dbuser"); 
    CONNECTION_PROPERTIES.put("v$session.osuser", System.getProperty("user.name").toString());
    try {
        CONNECTION_PROPERTIES.put("v$session.machine", InetAddress.getLocalHost().getCanonicalHostName());
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        System.out.println("Failed to determine hostname. Attempting with Localhost, this is unlikely to succeed.");
        e.printStackTrace();

        CONNECTION_PROPERTIES.put("v$session.machine", "localhost");
    } 
    CONNECTION_PROPERTIES.put("v$session.program", "GDS_Reports"); 
}
```

and I make a connection like this:

```
  DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver());
  Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(GlobalConstants.CONNECTION_STRING, GlobalConstants.CONNECTION_PROPERTIES);
```

But the table reports these connections:

```
MACHINE                                              OSUSER               DBUSER               FTIME
---------------------------------------- -------------------- -------------------- -----------------
wn7-18tl6m1.domain                                            dbuser               02-SEP-2011 14:46
wn7-18tl6m1.domain                                            dbuser               02-SEP-2011 14:46  
wn7-18tl6m1.domain                                            dbuser               02-SEP-2011 14:46
wn7-18tl6m1.domain                                            dbuser               02-SEP-2011 14:46
```

Comment: Which version of the oracle jdbc driver are you using?

Comment: I'm using odbjc14.jar. Does that help?

Comment: No I am asking re the getDriverVersion() as per http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/java.102/b14355/getsta.htm#i1008663

Comment: "JDBC driver version is 10.2.0.1.0XE"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some Oracle JDBC drivers have a bug so that OSUSER is not set see the [fixed bugs in 10.2.0.4](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/readme-jdbc-10204-093598.html) so you need to upgrade to a newer version to fix that.

Comment: I updated my driver to 11.2.0.2.0 and I still have the same problem.

Comment: Try not setting v$session.osuser as the default should be user.name - also check the value of user.name

Answer (score -2):

Oracle doesn't provide the osuser - it has to be told it by the client. You can code it into the java program. [Details here](http://www.integrigy.com/security-resources/analysis/Integrigy_Spoofing_Oracle_Session_Information.pdf).

Obviously, because you can do this, it is a pretty pointless security measure to whitelist on it.

Comment: That doc says that the user name can be spoofed not that Oracel does not provide it.